# Using Node without global install

Tags: node.js, global, local, electron

I'm working on a few Node & Electron (Atom Shell) projects and I'm curious how I could get them to work without the user having to install Node globally. I've seen a few applications do this by including a Node directory in their project that contains the Node.exe binary. How would you go about setting up a Node project to use this binary?

Edit: Thought I should add, I've searched everywhere for the answer to this, but only get unrelated results.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Node is bundled with Electron. An electron app should just work out of the box without needing to install Node